# Excel/Google Sheets - find matches if in 4 columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, match, formula, vlookup

I have 1 sheet with 4 columns (A,B,C,D), with each containing a list of emails.
I would like a way to create a new column of emails if they were found in all 4 of columns A-D.

Does anyone know of a workable formula to accomplish this? TIA

Comment: You are asking for two different approaches.  How Excel will do this and how Google sheets will do this may not be the same.  Please narrow the question to one approach.  Also please show how you attempted to solve this and where you hit the road block.

Comment: sorry, i was just hoping to open it to whatever someone had more experience with. i have no preference of one over the other. Most other attempts I'm made were just not applicable to 4 columns that would not require concatenation, or counifs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt to answer the question for an arbitrary number of columns in Excel, but the formula is too long:

```
=LET(range,A2:D7,
cols,COLUMNS(range),
join,range&"|"&COLUMN(range),
toCol,TOCOL(join),
toColRaw,TOCOL(range),
filter,FILTER(toCol,toColRaw<>""),
unique,UNIQUE(filter),
split,SORT(TEXTSPLIT(unique,"|")),
match,MATCH(split,split)-MATCH(split,split,0),
UNIQUE(FILTER(split,match=cols-1)))
```

[image]

You can extend it to five columns etc.

[image]

*EDIT*

You can use the same method in Google sheets. There is no Let function in GS but you can use Query to count the number of occurrences across columns:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   query(
       query(
           split(
               unique(
                   filter(
                        flatten(A1:D&"|"&column(A1:D)),
                        flatten(A1:D<>"")
                    )
               )
           ,"|")
         ,"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 label Count(Col2) ''"),
      "select Col1 where Col2="&columns(A1:D))
    )
```

Comment: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,C:C,0)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,D:D,0))),"No Match"))`

Comment: @tom-sharpe im receiving a name error with the formula, "the formula contains unrecognized text" im on excel office365

Comment: @scott-craner, your solution worked in excel, while it did not work in sheets due to the differences in column lengths. which is fine for me in any case

Comment: @DavidG As I stated in my comment functions are different between the two apps.  What works in one may not work in the other and vice versa.  It has nothing to do with the column lengths but the fact that FILTER in sheets is different than that in EXCEL..  As to the `#NAME` error, you probably do not have `TOCOL` or `TEXTSPLIT` yet

Comment: @Scott Craner's formula works in Google Sheets if you take out the ,"No Match"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(A:D); FLATTEN(A:D)<>""))
```

Comment: i understand this to give me a distinct list of the emails across all 4 columns but what im after is a list of the emails only where the unique email was found in each of the 4 columns

Comment: @DavidG can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?